# Converting words to numbers in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In excel I have a column of words which I need to convert to integers.  For example, I have a column of industries:

- Capital Goods,
- List item,
- Consumer Services,
- Technology, etc.

I want to replace each of these industries with an integer.

Below, something I was trying in VBA but which didn't work.  Here I am trying to loop through the column and if the word in the current cell is different from the word in the previous cell then I assign it a different integer.  (But it's not working)

```
Sub WordtoNum()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim varList
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim startrow, wsheet, tt As Integer

    ' Enter the worksheet and starting row
    '---------------------------------------
    wsheet = 2
    startrow = 2
    '---------------------------------------

    Set ws = Sheets(wsheet)
    Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[a1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    varList = rng1.Value2
    tt = 0

    For lngCnt = startrow To UBound(varList)
        If varList(lngCnt, 2) <> varList(lngCnt - 1, 2) Then _
           tt = tt + 1
        varList2(lngCnt, 2) = tt
    Next
    rng1.Value2 = varList
End Sub
```

This code is largely based on help I received in a recent, related post.

Comment: Please: 1) Show us an example of what you're trying to accomplish. 2) Be more specific than "it's not working". 3) Indent your code to make it easier for us mortals to read it. I did it for you this time. That said, `varList2` is neither declared nor used after it is assigned to. Did you mean `varList(lngCnt, 2) = tt`? Your question needs some cleaning up.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the build in Excel function, VLOOKUP? It looks up a word in a sorted column and returns a value from another column, but the same row as the match. [Read more on Office Help about VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

I realise the question you asked was how to do this in VBA, however, I'm not sure if you really wanted to use VBA as an exercise or just didn't know about this function?